# How to detect who restart my pc in office network

Tags: security, windows-7

i am very weak in server administration and networking. i work as a developer in a company. we have 15 employee in office sitting in different 15 pc. i am using windows 7 OS. i feel some one secretly restart my pc. we are using work group instead of domain.

so please suggest me how could i catch the thief who is restarting my pc.

is there any software which will maintain log of IP when some one restart my pc.

may be someone restart my pc by command or may be some one install a software running hiddenly in my pc which has two end like client & server and the wicked person use anyone to restart my pc.

so please suggest me how to fight against it and how to catch the thief. thanks

Comment: in most cases this is a Windows update

Comment: You sound a little paranoid. How do you know your machine is being restarted? Why do you suspect a "wicked" coworker?

Comment: Agreed. There is no data in this question that would even suggest someone is doing this to you intentionally. It's far more likely that Windows Update is doing this automatically.

Comment: i stopped windows update.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of shutdown event with date and time, we can take use of Event Viewer to filter Event ID: 1074 in System Event log

Steps:

1. Open Event Viewer with Eventvwr.exe
2. Navigate to Windows Logs\System
3. Right-Click on it and select "Filter Current Log…"
4. Filter: Event log: System Event ID: 1074
5. When you filter them, you can track down its shutdown type, date and time, and who has shutdown it.

For more information about shutdown event, please check this KB article:

Description of the Shutdown Event Tracker
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/293814

Hope this can be helpful!

Comment: thanks for your answer. i filter with 1074 and found no entry. probably some one install a software in my pc which is running secretly and wicked person user other end of that software which they use to restart  my pc. so can i block if any software try to restart my pc. can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: is there any free tool exist which keep track and log the ip if any one try to access my pc secretly in network by any command or by any software ?

Comment: Antivirus (to detect and stop local exploits) + Firewall (that closes all external connection destined to your computer) ....should be sufficient